# Wifiwizard is added to my config and package.json file but I can't find the import in my module.ts file

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

#### Prerequisites

Check all boxes if you have done the following:
- [x] Checked that your issue isn't already filed: https://github.com/tripflex/wifiwizard2/issues
- [x] Make sure you fill out the Issue Type below

#### Issue type

Select all that apply
- [x] Bug
- [ ] Enhancement
- [ ] Task
- [x] Question
- [ ] Other

#### Description

I'm using ionic framework. When I want to install the wifiwizard2 plugin I get no errors but i'm not able to use the plugin. The wifiwizard is added to my config and package.json file but I can't find the import in my module.ts file. Thanks in advance.

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. run  `sudo cordova plugin add https://github.com/tripflex/wifiwizard2`
2. run  `sudo npm i cordova-plugin-wifiwizard2`  or `sudo ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wifiwizard2`
3. [and so on...]

**Expected behavior:** Use the plugin

**Actual behavior:** cannot find import

**Reproduces how often:** 100%

#### Versions

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.10.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.1.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/nathancriel/Library/Android/sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.7.0
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61

#### Additional Information

config.xml
`https://github.com/tripflex/wifiwizard2.git" /`

package.json

`dependencies
"cordova-plugin-wifiwizard2": "git+https://github.com/tripflex/wifiwizard2.git",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WifiWizard is available as a global and does not need to be imported.
Try this :

```
declare var WifiWizard2: any;
```

**EDIT**
I try to use the plugin on my app and it work.

What i do :

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wifiwizard2`
  `npm i cordova-plugin-wifiwizard2`

On Home.ts :

`declare var WifiWizard2: any;`

After the platform is ready :

`WifiWizard2.getConnectedSSID()`

And the method is recognize on build.

Comment: I'm still not able to fetch methods. Wifiwizard still not reconized by my IDE. Is there anything else I should try or add?

Comment: i get: ERROR ReferenceError: WifiWizard2 is not defined. The plugin is also not in the list of cordova plugins. Does it need to be?

Comment: Yes he need to be i forget  the `add` in the cordova command .

Comment: And it is in the list of cordova plugins. But still wifiwizard is not defined.

Comment: Try to remove add platform.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do I need to add a platform? Remove platform?

Comment: `ionic cordova platform remove android`  `ionic cordova platform add android`  You can replace android by ios

Comment: Can you share ur config.xml

Comment: <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />

Comment: No cordova-plugin-wifiwizard? How do i add it manually? Isn't it added automatically when i run the commands above?

Comment: Share your package.json  on your question , it better to see.its added automatically in your config.xml  maybe  you have erro when you add the plugin.

Comment: If I run it on an android device it works. But I stil get the error when I run it in browser. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes its normal cordova don't work on browser. If u can upvote my answer  if it work.

Comment: Sam I'm using Ionic DevApp in device, its doesn't work in devapp too ?

Comment: Yes its use 'ionic serve' so. I think it doesn't work .